# Python3 Sine Function to fit Data

Tags: python-3.x, trigonometry, static-analysis

I have data which I broke into 28day slices. Here is a plot of the means of each of these slices.

[image]

I have to calculate some values from equation that fits the data reasonably well, and then find the correlation coefficient between those values and the means for each 28-day slice. Since I have one mean for each slice I have to find one value from the equation per slice.

I believe the equation is:

```
y = A sin(Bx - C) + D
```

But I am struggling to implement the equation for my data and find these values.

Comment: You may want to take a look at scipy fitting capabilities:
[link](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/FittingData.html)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, unfortunately I still can't figure out which values I should consider when calculating the equation.